# Condition on cacheable annotation on private property of Object

Tags: java, spring, annotations, ehcache, spring-cache

I have a use case in which I want to be able to cache the result of a method based on the property of a object. The property is private but exposes a public getter. (This can be changed, but i would not want to do that)

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "detailedData", key = "#id", condition = "#currentPackage.getSellingPrice() > -1")
public Map<String, Object> getDetailedTestData(int id,PackageEntity currentPackage) {
/**
some code
*/
}
```

`PackageEntity` class is

```
public class PackageEntity {

    private int sellingPrice;

    public int getSellingPrice() {
        return sellingPrice;
    }

    public void setSellingPrice(int sellingPrice) {
        this.sellingPrice = sellingPrice;
    }
  /**
  some other fields and their getter/setter
  */
}
```

Spring doc for conditional caching specifies how to use condition. However, this cahcing does not works as indicated by condition. It is simply caching all packages irrespective of selling price. 
I am unable to understand what am I doing wrong. Neither there are suitable examples that I can refer for this.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems SpEL also looks for public getters of the field if the specified field is private.

So the **field can be either public or have a public getter**

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "detailedData", key = "#id", condition ="#currentPackage.sellingPrice > -1")
public Map<String, Object> getDetailedTestData(int id,PackageEntity currentPackage) {
  /**
    some code
  */
}
```

So the above code worked alright for me.